# Mobile taxi apps for Tbilisi, Georgia

Tags: taxis, georgia-country

Which taxi apps work in Tbilisi, Georgia?  Is there an app that is more reliable or less expensive than the others?  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of early 2023, I had good experiences with **Bolt** in Tbilisi.

Cars usually arrive within 5 minutes, and the rides are very cheap by Western standards (usually less than 10GEL or $4)

Answer (score 1):

> Which taxi apps work in Tbilisi, Georgia?

[Yandex Go](https://go.yandex/en_ge/).